# Getting error when trying to fade-in one element and fade-out another at the same time using Xaml Storyboards

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I'm looking to finalize the look and feel of my application, and having difficulty applying a transition animation to what is a very basic issue.

Attached you can find the code I'm struggling with. I've commented out the setters which were what I was using during development and prototyping. They work just as I expect them to.

The storyboard transitions are not working in any way shape or form. Adding only one story board transition in combination with all or any of the setters "works" insofar as I don't get any runtime errors, but the transition isn't appearing at all.

I'm wondering if I'm perhaps not completely misunderstanding how storyboards work.

There error I'm getting is:

```
 Multiple animations in the same containing Storyboard cannot target the same property on a single element.
```

This is the simplified code:

```
<Grid>
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:1"/>
            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualState x:Name="StateA">
                <!--<VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="FirstElement.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    <Setter Target="SecondElement.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </VisualState.Setters>-->
                <Storyboard>
                    <PopOutThemeAnimation TargetName="SecondElement"/>
                    <PopInThemeAnimation TargetName="FirstElement"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="StateB">
                <!-- <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="FirstElement.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    <Setter Target="SecondElement.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </VisualState.Setters>-->
                <Storyboard>
                    <PopOutThemeAnimation TargetName="FirstElement"/>
                    <PopInThemeAnimation TargetName="SecondElement"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <Rectangle Name="FirstElement"
               Fill="Blue"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Width="200"
               Height="200" 
               DoubleTapped="GoToStateB" />

    <Rectangle Name="SecondElement"
               Fill="Red"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Width="200"
               Height="200" 
               DoubleTapped="GoToStateA" />
</Grid>
```

With the following simple code behind:

```
 private void GoToStateA(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // do something
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "StateA", true);
    }
    private void GoToStateB(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // do something else
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "StateB", true);
    }
```

**Edit**: the "solution" as pointed out by JustinXL is that the following Xaml element needs to be removed and the runtime error disappears:

```
            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:1"/>
            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
```

I'm not exactly clear why this is the case (genuine bug or simply an obscure design gotcha).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually a simpler solution is to completely remove the `Transitions` in `VisualStateGroup`.

Also note that I added a `IsHitTestVisible` change so the `FirstElement` would be able to receive clicks.

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup>
        <VisualState x:Name="StateA">
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="SecondElement.(UIElement.IsHitTestVisible)"
                        Value="False" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
            <Storyboard>
                <PopOutThemeAnimation TargetName="SecondElement" />
                <PopInThemeAnimation TargetName="FirstElement" />
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="StateB">
            <Storyboard>
                <PopOutThemeAnimation TargetName="FirstElement" />
                <PopInThemeAnimation TargetName="SecondElement" />
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Comment: Would you look at that! Removing the transition does get rid of the error. If this is not an outright bug, as you say, it's a very poorly designed component, as I would have never thought of turning over that rock. Thank you for chiming in!

Comment: @MB. Glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer it turns out is that the storyboard has to be in a VisualTransition and not in the VisualState itself, despite the fact that you can have animation storyboards in a visual state.

```
 <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition To="StateA">
                    <VisualTransition.Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <PopOutThemeAnimation TargetName="SecondElement"/>
                            <PopInThemeAnimation TargetName="FirstElement"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualTransition.Storyboard>
                </VisualTransition>

                <VisualTransition To="StateB">
                    <VisualTransition.Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <PopOutThemeAnimation TargetName="FirstElement"/>
                            <PopInThemeAnimation TargetName="SecondElement"/>
                        </Storyboard>                                               
                     </VisualTransition.Storyboard>
                </VisualTransition>
            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>

            <VisualState x:Name="StateA">
               <VisualState.Setters>
                   <Setter Target="FirstElement.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                   <Setter Target="SecondElement.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
               </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="StateB">
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="FirstElement.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                <Setter Target="SecondElement.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            </VisualState.Setters>

        </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Comment: No it doesn't have to be. Check out my answer. I suspect this is simply a bug in the stock animations.